# Brownian motion falling task.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider one dimensional brownian motion. Let's suppose it starts at point $a \in [0,L]$. If particles reach the bounds of segment, then they are falling down.

Let's suppose that it goes a long time and all particles are falling down, then what part of particles fall in left bound ?

I've thought about stochastic solution, but it more looks like something else. Any hints?

Comment: Is this brownian motion supposed to be a Weiner process, or a 1-D discrete random walk? Or something else?

Comment: Let $T$ be the time the particle falls down. On the one hand, $E[B_T]=a$. On the other hand, $B_T$ equals either $0$ or $L$, so $E[B_T]$ can also be written as$\dots$

Comment: @MarkFischler I guess it's supposed to be a Wiener process

Comment: @MikeEarnest $B_T $ is position of particles in moment $T$ ?

Comment: Yes, $B_t$ is the position of the particle at time $t$ for all $t\in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest but why $E(B_T) = a$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem

Comment: OK, the point you are missing is that $E[B_T]\neq a$ because the "last step" of any particle that falls off an edge no longer contributes to the average position of particles in the ensemble (for example, at the left edge, this particle contributes $0$ rather than some negative value).  For discrete RW the consideration that the change due to the number of discarded left and right steps equals the change from $Na$ at the start to $N_rL$ at the end allows you to quickly calculate the fraction of particles exiting to the left -- and this is not $0$ when $a=0$. Weiner process has similar effect.

Comment: @MarkFischler $B_t$ is the position of a single particle in the ensemble. It is assumed to follow a standard wiener process until it hits the boundary $\{0,L\}$ and hence, by definition of the Wiener process basically, $\mathbb{E}[B_t] = a$ for all $t$. You can extend this to the hitting time of the boundary $T$ using martingale techniques (by an optional stopping argument) since $B_{t \wedge T}$ is a bounded martingale. So we **do** have $\mathbb{E}[B_T] = a$ under these assumptions.

Comment: @RhysSteele and so we have something like : $\frac{L-a}{L}$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the probability a particle exits through $0$.

Comment: @RhysSteele thanks !

Comment: For a discrete RW with step size $1$ the probability of falling off to the left is $\frac{L+1-a}{L+2}$. This is dependent, therefore, on the step size for any given combination of $a,L$. The Weiner process is scale-independent so that can't happen for the Weiner process. I think the answer there is just $1-a/L$, which means that if you start at one edge, you will fall off that edge with probability $1$.